# I tried installing nvm on mac but it shows already installed and then when i try to get its version or use any commands it errors out

Tags: python, node.js, macos, npm, nvm

```
-MacBook-Air ~ % brew install nvm
Warning: nvm 0.39.5 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 0.39.5, run:
  brew reinstall nvm
-MacBook-Air ~ % nvm --version
zsh: command not found: nvm
-MacBook-Air ~ % nvm help
zsh: command not found: nvm
-MacBook-Air ~ % nvm install v11.0.0
zsh: command not found: nvm
-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

I tried installing nvm on mac but it shows already installed and then when i try to get its version or use any commands it errors out

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue with the help of an article:

I skipped sourcing, which led to the issue:

I need to use:

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```